# Is attention cache useful during transformer pretraining?

Tags: transformer, nvidia

I am looking at the MegatronLM implementation, and the only thing that is cached are the results of `xK` and `xV` computation:

https://github.com/NVIDIA/Megatron-LM/blob/b44dca25727c294a7f825e74a3c4a53744cc8404/megatron/model/transformer.py#L339

Which are then stacked with past values and still the full `QK` matrix is computed. The computation of keys and queries does not seem that expensive in comparison.